# How to drag and drop a list of files onto a window

Tags: windows, drag-and-drop

I have a very long list of files of type .png located in a .txt file. Is there any way I can drag and drop this list onto a running Windows program? I know for a fact this program accepts files when I drag-and-drop them from Windows Explorer onto the running window. (An explanation of how drag-and-drop works might be helpful.)

Comment: [Drag and Drop (OLE)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96826a87.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Windows programs consume "messages" from the operating system in a message loop or message pump.  Drag and drop works on this level - the application receives a "incoming dragged stuff" message - it's on the same level as what happens when you click a button or resize the window.

An individual program can have any behavior the programmer creates and respond to a message in any way it wants.  So a programmer would have to build into his or her program the ability to understand the text you drag on top of it and act the way you are describing.

COM components and such can hook into to add or modify these behaviors (so it's possible to do this), but AFAIK standard out-of-the-box Windows doesn't do this or provide any such utility that makes drag and drop act like you are describing.  I don't know of a utility that provides this.

Something tells me `gvim` or other scriptable text editor could do this though.

If your list of files is separated by newlines, and you can replace those newlines with a space, you might consider converting it to a space-separated list of files, and use `cmd.exe` to invoke the command's executable with the filelist as the arguments manually.

Answer (score 0):

The app would need to have the facility to parse the dropped text.

Dropping a file hands it a specific reference to work with - it can start to look inside the file, see if it's something it can handle & then deal with it apropriately.

Dropping text it has to 'know' how to deal with the text - a completely different problem.
The text may be a file reference, starting file:// or a URL, http:// ... or it could just be a name mypic.png
It would be able to handle the first 2 as established protocols, but what would it do with mypic.png? It isn't a png file, just the name of one. It wouldn't know where to start to find where it ought to be; if such a file existed on your local computer, or on a web site somewhere.